# "AUTH-010 Access token provided is invalid or expired". How to solve this error?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I have four (essentially identical) Forge apps, but each with a separate callback server, (which I am using identically). Unfortunately, one of the four generates the above error. My code is identical for all four, as are the users/projects (I am testing the same BIM 360 project & members via each server). All four Apps have "BIM 360 Account Administration" (BIM360 API) and "Document Management" (Document Management API) access.
All four seem to work perfectly for generating the 2- and 3-legged OAuth tokens (2LT/3LT), and making the initial call to Get Hubs (Data Management API) using the 3LT. From there, three apps succeed in making all of my other calls; however the fourth server (Production, of course) fails immediately on the next call to Get Projects (hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects, BIM360 API), with the above error. The call is immediate, so it can't have expired; nor can I understand how it is invalid.

I have run into this same error several times in the last few months; but I can't recall a specific fix. Code is the same; member access is the same (because it's the same member); 3LT OAuth is clearly working because I am able to make the Hubs call; I've never had any trouble before with the 2LT, but I can't verify that it's still good in this case. Troubleshooting on the server is going to be a challenge.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer originally posted to question by OP:

> I figured it out, but hopefully this will help someone else. I was
> using the wrong URL to get the 2-legged token.
> "/authentication/v1/authenticate" gets the 2-legged token,
> "/authentication/v1/gettoken" gets the 3-legged token. Some API calls
> require a 2-legged token, and some require a 3-legged token (and some
> will take either). It is not always obvious what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you reolved the issue yourself, but just FYI. Each endpoint has a required `Authentication Context`. It will help understnad what kind of OAuth workflow and access token your need for calling this endpoint. For example,

- [GET projects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-GET/) of BIM360 Admin API accept 2LO access token only.
  [image]
- [GET issues](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/) of BIM360 Issues API accepts 3LO access toke only
  [image]

However, some endpoints support both 2LO and 3LO. e.g. [GET Hubs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/) of Data Management API.

[image]

We can find the exaplaination under Forge OAth API documentation [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/developers_guide/basics/).

[image]